# is there a function to do this

Tags: javascript, lodash, underscore.js, marionette

I'm looking for a way to get the same functionality of the Lodash _.forIn() Method but without using Lodash. I can use Underscore however.

This is what the method does
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-forin-method/?ref=gcse

Comment: Seems to be similar to standard [for....in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: Why not `for (let x in obj) { callback(obj[x], x); }`? Why is a library needed?

Comment: Your question improves if you include information on the things you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic recipe for `_.forIn` was given in a comment by @VLAZ:

```js
function forIn(collection, iteratee) {
    for (var key in collection) {
        iteratee(collection[key], key, collection);
    }
    // return the collection to uphold Underscore convention
    return collection;
}

// using the above to output the contents of an object
forIn({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, console.log);
// 1 a {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
// 2 b {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
// 3 c {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

All the iteratee shorthand niceness can be added by taking the `iteratee` through `_.iteratee` first:

```js
import _ from 'underscore';

function forIn(collection, iteratee, context) {
    // turn shorthands into functions
    iteratee = _.iteratee(iteratee, context);
    for (var key in collection) {
        iteratee(collection[key], key, collection);
    }
    return collection;
}
```

To add it to the Underscore namespace, so you can use it in chaining and OOP notation, use `_.mixin`:

```js
import { mixin } from 'underscore';

mixin({forIn});

// now you can do things like this:
_.chain(someObject)
.forIn(someFunction)
.sortBy(someProperty)
.andSoForth();
```

Comment: Thank you @Julian
say I had a collection
`var collection = {
  'a':  1,
  'b':  2,
  'c':  3
};`

how would i output this using your examples

Comment: I presume you mean that `collection` is the input. What output do you want to see?

Comment: if you were to just output the values

Comment: I have now illustrated the usage in the first code example.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your object to underscore's `_.map` (if you want the result to be an array), `_.mapObject` (if you want the result to be an object) or `_.each` functions and access the keys

```
_.map({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, (item, key, collection) => console.log(key))
> a
> b
> c
```

Comment: This is not the same as `forIn()` since it will not go through the prototype chain.